# ffmpeg :how to apply animation in multiple images

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to merge number of selected images from gallery to a video template in order to make video status or short video in a android app, I am able to merge the selected images in the video using below cammand    now i want to add animation

```
 ArrayList<String> cmd2 = new ArrayList<>();
    cmd2.add("-y");
    cmd2.add("-i");
    if (video_temp_path!= null){
        cmd2.add(video_temp_path);
    }else {
        cmd2.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/Download/happy.mp4");
    }


    for (int no = 0; no < paths.length; no++) {
        cmd2.add("-i");

        cmd2.add(paths[no]);

    }

    cmd2.add("-filter_complex");



    cmd2.add("[0][1]overlay=x=100:y=200:enable='between(t,3,8)'[v1];" +
            "[v1][2]overlay=x=100:y=200:enable='between(t,10,15)'[v2];" +
            "[v2][3]overlay=x=100:y=200:enable='gt(t,17)'[v3]");
    cmd2.add("-map");
    cmd2.add("[v3]");
    cmd2.add("-map");
    cmd2.add( "0:a");
    cmd2.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/Download/output.mp4");
```

but now i want to add fade in out animation to images  so I am using this cammand generated by chatgpt but its giving me error

```
  ArrayList<String> cmd2 = new ArrayList<>();
   cmd2.add("-y");
   cmd2.add("-i");

   if (video_temp_path != null) {
    cmd2.add(video_temp_path);
  } else {
    cmd2.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
            "/Download/happy.mp4");
}

for (int no = 0; no < paths.length; no++) {
    cmd2.add("-loop");
    cmd2.add("1"); // loop the image

    cmd2.add("-t");
    cmd2.add("5"); // duration of the image

    cmd2.add("-i");
    cmd2.add(paths[no]);

    cmd2.add("-filter_complex");
    cmd2.add("[1:v]fade=in:st=0:d=1[tin];" +
            "[1:v]fade=out:st=4:d=1[tout];" +
            "[0:v][tin]overlay=x=100:y=200" +
            "[v1];" +
            "[v1][tout]overlay=x=100:y=200:enable='between(t,10,15)'[v2];" +
            "[v2][2:v]overlay=x=100:y=200:enable='gt(t,17)'[v3]");

    cmd2.add("-map");
    cmd2.add("[v3]");
    cmd2.add("-map");
    cmd2.add("0:a");
}

cmd2.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
        "/Download/output.mp4");
```

error is

```
 Option map (set input stream mapping) cannot be applied to input url /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/temp/1677570327312.jpg -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
```

2023-03-01 12:50:50.707 5950-6326/com.android.mergevideo E/mobile-ffmpeg: Error parsing options for input file /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/temp/1677570327312.jpg.
2023-03-01 12:50:50.707 5950-6326/com.android.mergevideo E/mobile-ffmpeg: Error opening input files:
2023-03-01 12:50:50.707 5950-6326/com.android.mergevideo E/mobile-ffmpeg: Invalid argument